# Indexing a large JSON using NEST

Tags: c#, json, elasticsearch, .net-core, nest

I'm trying to add a large JSON(around 22k lines) file to my ElasticSearch index but I am unable to do so since I am getting error response from ElasticSearch whatever I tried. I'm using ElasticSearch 7.6.2 and I'm using NEST to communicate with ElasticSearch.

I will add only the code related to the problem.

First I create connection settings like this:

```
_settings = new ConnectionSettings()
                               .DefaultMappingFor<string>(m => m  // I've put string here because that is the return type of File.ReadAllText() function
                               .IndexName("jsonindex")
                               );
```

Then I create my ElasticClient:

```
_elasticClient = new ElasticClient(_settings);
```

I've created my index succesfully like this:

```
_elasticClient.Indices.Create("jsonindex", c => c
                       .Settings(s => s
                           .NumberOfShards(1)));
```

When everything is setup, I do the following:

```
var json = File.ReadAllText("path\to\file.json"); //read the json file 
var indexResponse = _elasticClient.IndexDocument(jsonToSend); //try to index it, but this is where I get the error message
```

I get the following error:

```
Request failed to execute. Call: Status code 400 from: POST /jsonindex/_doc. ServerError: Type: mapper_parsing_exception Reason: "failed to parse" CausedBy: "Type: not_x_content_exception Reason: "Compressor detection can only be called on some xcontent bytes or compressed xcontent bytes""
```

I've also tried calling the .Index() method and specify the index name as the second argument, but result is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like I was not going in the right direction while using the high level client, I accessed the low level client like this:

```
_elasticClient.LowLevel.Index<StringResponse>("jsonindex", json);
```

and it worked on the first try, it might help someone who was using high level client like me. (Note: I assume there is a way to achieve what I wanted to do using high level client, I just haven't figured it out yet)